# Save ppsd plot as csv file in Python

Tags: python, plot

I have this code:

```
from obspy.core import read
from obspy.io.xseed import Parser
from obspy.signal import PPSD
from obspy.imaging.cm import pqlx
import glob

#read mseed data
for data in glob.glob("F:/SKRIPSI/MSEED/*.mseed"):
    st=read(data)
    tr=st.select()[0]

    #read dataless
    for dataless in glob.glob("F:/SKRIPSI/MSEED/*.dseed"):
        if (data.rsplit(".", 1)[0])==(dataless.rsplit(".", 1)[0]):
            parser=Parser(dataless)

            #plot ppsd
            ppsd=PPSD(tr.stats, metadata=parser)
            ppsd.add(st)
            ppsd.plot(filename=(data.rsplit(".", 1)[0]) + "_01_PPSD.png")
            ppsd.plot(filename=(data.rsplit(".", 1)[0]) + "_02_PPSD cumulative.png", cumulative=True)
            ppsd.plot(filename=(data.rsplit(".", 1)[0]) + "_03_PPSD pqlx.png", cmap=pqlx)
            ppsd.plot_spectrogram(filename=(data.rsplit(".", 1)[0]) + "_04_PPSD spectrogram.png",show=False)
            ppsd.plot_temporal([0.1, 1, 10],filename=(data.rsplit(".", 1)[0]) + "_05_PPSD temporal.png",show=False)
```

and I want to save this (as shown below) part of the plot to csv files. I've tried to change the png into csv, and used `.savetxt` but it's not that easy right... I'm new in all of this coding stuff. Please help?

```
ppsd.plot_temporal([0.1, 1, 10],filename=(data.rsplit(".", 1)[0]) + "_05_PPSD temporal.png",show=False)
```

I've tried using pandas too but it doesn't work:

```
import pandas as pd    

temp=ppsd.plot_temporal([0.1, 1, 10],filename=(data.rsplit(".", 1)[0]) + "_05_PPSD temporal.png",show=False)
csvtemp=pd.DataFrame(temp)
csvtemp.to_csv((data.rsplit(".", 1)[0]) + "_05_PPSD temporal.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

There is no error but the csv file is empty.

Thanks!